# Redirect to a page if shared from Facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share-button

I don't know whether is this possible. I am creating a site in PHP. Is it possible to detect the previous url is from facebook/twitter, and if yes redirect to an another page?

In detail
I have page A and B. There is a share button in page B. On clicking that button it will post title, image, description etc of the page B to facebook. But clicking that in facebook it will redirect to page A.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your pages are on the same domain you can use sessions.

For external pages you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`.

I.e.

```
if ( $parts = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] ) ) {
   if($parts['host'] == "www.facebook.com"){
      //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One doubt. When share page B, its title, description, image etc will be fetched by facebook. If i use the above code, will facebook shows title of page A or page B???

Comment: @user3392772 This variable will only return the URL of the last page. If you have passed title as a variable in URL you will be able to access it. Otherwise not.

Comment: How to pass title as variable in url? Sorry I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @user3392772 I.e. xxx.com?title=abc If you have title variable like in this example you can then get it using the prase_url() method.